# Missing Resource file when building with Android.mk

Tags: android, makefile, android-drawable, android-make

I have resource files in res/drawable-xhdpi folder of my Android project.

Android Studio doesnt have any problem building the application and it runs fine.

I am moving the project to Android.mk and i get the following  at build time "warning: no entries written for drawable/resource_name". When I try to run the built apk, I get a Resource not found error.

Can any one please guide me as to what I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `mm`, do a full build of the app perhaps? (using `make`)

Also, there was this error I faced once, though I am not completely sure if it is applicable here. You should have one copy in `res/drawable` irrespective of whichever overlay you're putting it in. It is because the compiler first checks `drawable` and then overrides it with the device specific overlay. If it doesn't find it there, it will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, cleaning the project helps. Check with that first.

Comment: I am doing a clean build every time using Android.mk. The command is mm -B

Comment: Instead of doing `mm`, do a full build of the app perhaps? (using `make`)

Comment: Also, there was this error I faced once, though I am not completely sure if it is applicable here. You should have one copy in `res/drawable` irrespective of whichever overlay you're putting it in. It is because the compiler first checks `drawable` and then overrides it with the device specific overlay. If it doesn't find it there, it will throw an error. If this helps, I will add this as an answer.

Comment: @AnindyaDutta, your solution is correct. AOSP (Android.mk) and Gradle builds are two different beasts. Please add your comment as an answer.